# Append the same key value to a list of dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, vectorization

I have a list of dict and I want to append the same key value to all dict.
For example :

```
l = [
    {'name' : 'abc', 'age' : '20', 'city' : 'abc'},
    {'name' : 'def', 'age' : '20', 'city' : 'def'},
    {'name' : 'hij', 'age' : '20', 'city' : 'hij'},
    {'name' : 'klm', 'age' : '20', 'city' : 'klm'},
    {'name' : 'nop', 'age' : '20', 'city' : 'nop'}
    ]

for d in l:
    d['date'] = '30/10/2019'
```

output :

```
{'name': 'abc', 'age': '20', 'city': 'abc', 'date': '30/10/2019'}
{'name': 'def', 'age': '20', 'city': 'def', 'date': '30/10/2019'}
{'name': 'hij', 'age': '20', 'city': 'hij', 'date': '30/10/2019'}
{'name': 'klm', 'age': '20', 'city': 'klm', 'date': '30/10/2019'}
{'name': 'nop', 'age': '20', 'city': 'nop', 'date': '30/10/2019'}
```

So it's work but in my real case I have more values (2000 dicts with 40 keys). And I want know if there is a way to append the date to each dict without a for.

Comment: There is no way to append the date without some kind of looping.

Comment: Write your own getter which will return date

Comment: FWIW, 2000 dicts with 40 keys is not big. Your solution should be perfectly fine. Are you having trouble with it? Is it too slow? Not working as expected?

Comment: Just ran a quick check on performance using pandas, and looping seems to be much faster. Can't see what is the problem with performance. This `for i in l: i['date'] = '30/10/2019'` takes `500us` for a list of 2000 dicts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use a for-loop.

However, in the spirit of actually answering the question as asked, you could use *map()* to run an implicit for-loop at C-speed:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> from collections import deque
>>> from operator import setitem

>>> _ = deque(map(setitem, l, repeat('date'), repeat('30/10/2019')), maxlen=0)

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(l)
[{'age': '20', 'city': 'abc', 'date': '30/10/2019', 'name': 'abc'},
 {'age': '20', 'city': 'def', 'date': '30/10/2019', 'name': 'def'},
 {'age': '20', 'city': 'hij', 'date': '30/10/2019', 'name': 'hij'},
 {'age': '20', 'city': 'klm', 'date': '30/10/2019', 'name': 'klm'},
 {'age': '20', 'city': 'nop', 'date': '30/10/2019', 'name': 'nop
```